# WooCommerce - Cancel, Refund and Restock

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a fraud prevention plugin which sends a flag whether to accept or reject the order based on several parameters.

If the flag is set to reject I need to,

1. Cancel the order
2. Refund
3. Restock

I see a cancel method in `WC_Order` but it is for before payment. But I need to do this after payment.